# Dynamic Chart Not Selecting the correct data - albeit the correct OFFSET

Tags: excel

**Goal**:

What I am trying to achieve (see the screenshot of the spreadsheet so that it is easier to follow):
[image]

I have a column J that lists dates (goes all the way up to and including 2017-09-01) and a dropdown in cell M2 that allows you to select one of the following: '2017-08-01' or '2017-07-27'. **If** you select '2017-08-01' then the chart plots the K column from '2017-08-01' to '2017-09-01' (both dates inclusive), with the corresponding labels. This works as expected. Should work in the same manner for 2017-07-27 (i.e. would plot column K from 2017-07-27 to 2017-08-01).

**Problem**:

For the latter case above, it does not work, and in fact you can see the output in the screenshot. It for some reason shifts everything and starts plotting from 2017-08-01, while labels are correct for dates...

**Explanation of mechanics**:

I have achieved the dynamic ranges with the offset function. The length over which to make the selection, is determined by start and end. (what is curious is that if I go to named ranges Ctrl+F3, the data for what to plot is determined correctly... So I am at a loss).

Here are the formulas in start and end cells:
[image]
selectedMonth is the namedRange for cell M2 (the date dropdown).
And here are the formulas for dynamic chart's y values:
[image]
And here are the dates (i.e. exactly the same as above, but with no column offset; and that is what is weird, because the dates are working correctly...):
[image]

Comment: i think it is because excel changes it into static reference... And then only works in that reference, so I need to use VBA as per here: https://peltiertech.com/dynamic-chart-source-data/